# Javascript not returning the correct value for a radio button that is initially hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my jQuery function I have:

```
var is_employee = $('input[name=is_employee_1]:checked').val();
```

It's supposed to get the value from the html block below:

```
<div id="employee_question_1" class="unavailable">
     Is this attendee an employee of an ADA Dentist? 
     <input type="radio" name="is_employee_1" value="yes" id="is_employee_yes_1" class="cb_course is_employee_1" /><label for="is_employee_yes_1">Yes</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="radio" name="is_employee_1" value="no" id="is_employee_no_1" class="cb_course  is_employee_1" /><label for="is_employee_no_1">No</label> 
 </div>
```

the `class="unavailable"` is utilized by

```
$(".unavailable").addClass('hidden');
```

This is to hide certain fields that aren't available to all registration types. The CSS for the hidden class is:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

The field is later unhidden by JavaScript, but when I try to fetch the value, it returns `"no"` regardless of what is actually checked.

I also tried to fetch the value using:

```
var checkedValue = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('is_employee_1');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
```

which always returns `no`.

Comment: just do it like this
$(document).on("click","input[name=is_employee_1", function() {
var is_employee = $(this).val();
});

Comment: even in the click method the value return by $this.val() returned `no`.  i did get my form working by examining the `id` of the element that was clicked instead of the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You used `document.getElementsByClassName('is_employee_1')` but there is no element with that class so your if statement condition is never true.

Comment: fixed that, now the plain javascript method also always return **no**

Comment: i changed `class="cb_course"` to `class="cb_course is_employee_1"`

Comment: there are always two elements

Comment: Is the pure javascript function firing on a click or when does it actually fire?